# Is the "Bay Tour" flight path documented, or is it a more informal route? Are there similar flight paths for other cities?

Tags: general-aviation, flight-planning, class-b-airspace

During my Private Pilot's Licence days out in San Francisco, we often flew a "Bay Tour": a sightseeing flight northbound from San Jose through SFO's Class B , over the city and Golden Gate Bridge, then east to Oakland and south to return to SJC. Local approach controllers were familiar with this route, and a pilot could file a flight plan for a Bay Tour with everyone knowing what he was talking about. In addition, the tower at SFO would often go out of their way to give aircraft on a Bay Tour a better view of A380's and 787's out of SFO. However, I can't find any official information on it. Is it a published procedure, or just something that everyone out there has come to know about? Do similar flight plans exist for other cities and if so, where can I find information on them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There certainly are similar routes - the **Niagara *Scenic Falls* route**, given in FAR [93.71](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library%5CrgFAR.nsf/0/C119237853E17565862571650050AE28?OpenDocument) comes to mind.  ([FAR 93 has plenty of these, by the way](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5;node=14%3A2.0.1.3.11).)

> Comply with the following procedures when conducting flight over the
>   area described in paragraph (a) of this section:
>
> (1) Fly a clockwise pattern;
>
> (2) Do not proceed north of the Rainbow Bridge;
>
> (3) Prior to joining the pattern, broadcast flight intentions on
>   frequency 122.05 Mhz, giving altitude and position, and monitor the
>   frequency while in the pattern;
>
> (4) Use the Niagara Falls airport altimeter setting. Contact Niagara
>   Falls Airport Traffic Control Tower to obtain the current altimeter
>   setting, to facilitate the exchange of traffic
>   advisories/restrictions, and to reduce the risk of midair collisions
>   between aircraft operating in the vicinity of the Falls. If the
>   Control Tower is closed, use the appropriate Automatic Terminal
>   Information Service (ATIS) Frequency;
>
> (5) Do not exceed 130 knots;
>
> (6) Anticipate heavy congestion of VFR traffic at or above 3,500 feet
>   MSL; and
>
> (7) Use caution to avoid high-speed civil and military aircraft
>   transiting the area to or from Niagara Falls Airport.

Answer (score 6):

As a Bay Area pilot, I've wondered this too.  It appears to be an **unofficial but widely-understood local custom**, similar to the not-always-charted VFR reporting points commonly in use at many local airports.

Moreover, it seems there isn't just one "Bay Tour".  Instead, I think that phrase generally tells the controllers that you're on a sightseeing flight rather than simply trying to get from point A to point B.

Answer (score 5):

There is not one official "Bay Tour" flight route. However, there are general guidelines to follow. [This local flight instructor's site](http://sjflight.com/BayTour.htm) explains this and offers suggestions of where you can get a map. [Here is a flight briefing for one possible route](http://www.wvfc.org/request-information/newsletters/pilot-decision-making-3).

In general, there are [VFR Flyway Planning Charts](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/productcatalog/planningcharts/VFRFlyway/) that you can use in certain areas of the country. [San Francisco has one of these](https://skyvector.com/?ll=37.652928397184645,-122.26654453333488&chart=156&zoom=5).

> Flyway Planning Charts depict flight paths and altitudes recommended for use to by-pass areas heavily traversed by large turbine-powered aircraft. Ground references on these charts provide a guide for visual orientation. VFR Flyway Planning charts are designed for use in conjunction with TACs and are not to be used for navigation.

Example section of a VFR Flyway Chart:

[image: Portion of a VFR Flyway Chart]